# Charging MB Pro 16" with both monitor and power cord?

Tags: power

We have a current MBP 16" connected to a Dell monitor that is not providing enough power to adequately charge it. Is there any harm in connect both the monitor and the power cord, given they are both providing charge?

Answer (score 0):

No, there’s no harm in connecting both the monitor and the charger simultaneously.

If you experience heating, try by connecting the monitor and charger on opposite sides.